# Sequence Convergence Homework question

Tags: real-analysis

Show that a sequence {s$_n$} converges to a limit L iff the sequence {s$_n$-L} converges to zero.

I know that a sequence {s$_n$} converges to a number L if the terms of the sequence get closer and closer to L. Can I use this information to show this.

Comment: Do you know the $\epsilon$ definition of convergence?

Comment: The main thing here is $s_n-L = (s_n-L) -0$.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, a sequence $s_n$ converges to $L$ when, for every $\epsilon>0$, there is some $N$ for which $|s_n-L|<\epsilon$ for all $n>N$.

Now write down what it would mean for the sequence $t_n=s_n-L$ to converge to $0$, and observe that you already know this statement is true.